# Dialogue keeps being stuck at last sentence

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a dialogue script so that I can display sentences on different NPC's.
I also have added a continue button so it goes from sentence to sentence.

The problem is that for some reason the last dialog gets stuck and keeps replaying if I interact after all sentences have played.

What I want is to replay all sentences that I added onto the NPC.

*I also wanted to ask if there was a way to **NOT** use the continue button? And let the text type itself out after a certain amount of time. Like a real conversation.*

As you can see I added the lines on the right
[image: Lines]

The first line printed
[image: Lines]

The second line printed

[image: Lines]

The third line printed
[image: Lines]

Starts placing the last line back to back every time I interact **UNLESS** I click the Button, because then it clears. But it still replays the last sentence every time instead of reverting back to the 1st.
[image: Lines]

Dialogue Script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

  [System.Serializable]
public class Dialogue2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject dialogBox;  // Attach ui image to this
    public Text npcname;          // Attach UI text gameObject
    public Text dialogText;       // Attach UI text gameObject
    public string NPC;            // What is he/she called?
    public string[] sentences;
    public bool playerInRange;    // Is the Player in range?
    public float typingSpeed;
    private int index;

    public GameObject continueButton;



    public AudioSource SignUpSfx;
    public AudioSource SignDownSfx;


    void Update()
    {
      if(dialogText.text == sentences[index]){
        continueButton.SetActive(true);
      }

        // Player in range and E is hit
      if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && playerInRange)
      {
        if(dialogBox.activeInHierarchy)
        {
          dialogBox.SetActive(false);
          SignDownSfx.Play();
        }

        else
        {
          dialogBox.SetActive(true);
          StopAllCoroutines();
          StartCoroutine(Type());
          npcname.text = NPC;
          SignUpSfx.Play();
        }
    }
}

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {

      if(other.CompareTag("Entity"))
      {
        playerInRange = true;
      }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {

      if(other.CompareTag("Entity") && dialogBox.activeInHierarchy == true)
      {
        SignDownSfx.Play();
      }

      if(other.CompareTag("Entity"))
      {

        playerInRange = false;
        dialogBox.SetActive(false);
      }
    }

    IEnumerator Type(){

      foreach(char letter in sentences[index].ToCharArray()){
        dialogText.text += letter;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(typingSpeed);

      }
    }

    public void NextSentence(){

      continueButton.SetActive(false);

      if(index < sentences.Length - 1){
        index++;
        dialogText.text = "";
        StartCoroutine(Type());
      } else {
        dialogText.text = "";
        continueButton.SetActive(false);

      }
    }

}
```

Comment: Should you reset `index` within `else` block?

Comment: @Johnny If I reset the Index in the else block I get the following error "returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just change:

```cs
if(index < sentences.Length - 1){
        index++;
        dialogText.text = "";
        StartCoroutine(Type());
      } else {
        dialogText.text = "";
        continueButton.SetActive(false);

      }
```

To this?

```cs
if(index < sentences.Length - 1){
        index++;
        dialogText.text = "";
        StartCoroutine(Type());
      } else {
        dialogText.text = "";
        continueButton.SetActive(false);
        index = 0;
      }
```

Comment: One last question. After I finish all 2 or 3 sentences if I don't press continue it doesn't seem to reset. It wants me to press continue to go to the blank line. Is there a way to reset the conversation at all times? Even when I leave it at lets say line 1 ?

Comment: What do you mean? Can you do an example?

Comment: Well what happens is exactly the same as the last image. If I interact with the npc, and I press e again (Interaction) it closes down the dialoguebox. but when I interact again it copies the first written text back to back. What I want to achieve is that each time you interact (Dialogbox opens and closes) I want the lines to reset back to the beginning

Comment: For this case you need to reset the index in your `Update` method.
`if(dialogBox.activeInHierarchy)
        {
          index = 0;
          dialogBox.SetActive(false);
          SignDownSfx.Play();
        }`